# How to check if a Laravel model has a one-to-one relationship with either one of two other models?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, relational-database

Im pretty new to Laravel and theres something Im failing to achieve about model relationships. Suppose I have a User model, a Ferrari model and a Lamborghini model, and that the User model can have a one-to-one relationship with either only the Ferrari model or only the Lamborghini model. So, if the user has a Ferrari, he sure doesn't have a Lamborghini, and vice versa.

How can I create a method on the User model that checks with which of these two cars the user has a relationship (if it has any at all)?

Heres one of the things I tried:

```
class Ferrari extends Model { ... }

class Lamborghini extends Model { ... }

class User extends Model {
   // Rest of class here
   public function car() {
      return $this->hasOne( Ferrari::class ) ?? $this->hasOne( Lamborghini::class );
   }
}
```

This doesnt work because `hasOne` doesnt return `null` if the Ferrari model is not related, but Im showing this to give an idea of what Im trying to achieve.

Ideally, the solution should also involve an interface in case I want to add more cars in the future, something like this:

```
interface Car { ... }

class Ferrari extends Model implements Car { ... }

class Lamborghini extends Model implements Car { ... }

class User extends Model {
   // Rest of class here
   public function car() {
      return $this->hasOne( Car::class );
   }
}
```

Although of course this doesnt work because interfaces cant be instantiated, but again, its just to give an idea.

Comment: What's preventing you from using just a Car model? You can just have a `brand` attribute to differentiate the car if it's a Ferrari or Lambo.

Comment: Hey, this is just an example, in my real use-case I must have two different models because I have two different database tables.

Comment: Typically, if you're trying to relate a Model to either Model A or Model B, you'd use a Polymorphic Relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships. Check those docs and see if that fits your use case, otherwise, you might need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75997038/edit) with more details (or more relevant details, since the obvious answer with this code's context is to not use multiple Models, but rather a single `Car` model with an associated `Brand`).